# I want to make a simple app which requires a simple pin code auth only

Tags: flutter, authentication, flutter-packages, pin-code

Some app which includes personal info often requires login function,
but I want to minimize it into pin code only.

I googled all over the place, but I am a bit confused because in many cases
pin auth means what requires SMS authentication or NATIVE_APP PIN authentication.

I just want my app to ask 4~6 simple pin codes, instead of full login function.
But I don't know which flutter package I should use...
And one more, should I use the local storage or the firebase?

If you have no time, a link or short notice will also be truly appreciated.
Thank you for reading.

I googled 'pin auth', 'pin code', etc. for several days...
But all of them are either too out-dated or not for my case.
There's a possibility that I don't know the keywords to search, since I am a newbie here.
Help me out with your ideas please...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth). It includes authentication with biometrics too.

```
try {
  final bool didAuthenticate = await auth.authenticate(
      localizedReason: 'Please authenticate');
  // ···
} on PlatformException {
  // ...
}
```